# Периодическое пополнение списка данными из Infrastructure в UI

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm, clean-architecture

Пытаюсь научиться в WPF + CleanArchitecture, для начала разбил приложение на слои и обозначил их специфику.

При нажатии в приложении кнопки "Включить"

```
public MainWindowViewModel(
IWindow window, 
IBackup backup)
{
    EnableBackup.Subscribe(async _ =>
    { 
        backup.Enable();
    });
}
```

включается отслеживание в определённой папке, добавились ли туда новые файлы.

```
public void Enable()
{
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(ApplicationSettings.Default.SourcePath)
    {
        IncludeSubdirectories = ApplicationSettings.Default.IsSearchSubdir,
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };
    watcher.NotifyFilter |= NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
}
```

Если файл создался то далее по event уже вызываем OnCreated()

```
 System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
 {
     CopiedFiles.Value.Add(new CopiedFile
     {
         Time = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(),
         FileName = (e.Name.Split('\\')).Last()
     });
 });
```

который получит название файла и время создания. Проблема в том, что функция проверки создания файла находится в слое Infrastructure, и обратное обращение запрещено, что бы заполнить свойство

```
public ReactiveProperty<IList<CopiedFile>> CopiedFiles { get; } = new();
```

Как можно решить эту проблему, может я куда то совсем не туда копаю?

Comment: `а ViewModels соответственно в UI` - вот ваша проблема. UI это View слой, который вообще ничего не должен знать про другие слои, а у вас он вдруг что-то запускает, на что-то подписывается, что-то делает... У вас отслеживание и прочая логика по работе с файлами должна быть в Model, в View должен быть только вид и привязки, ну а в ViewModel подписывание на событие Model, вызов ее методов, ну и создание свойств для привязки UI. И да, если учите, оооочень советую отказаться от всех фреймворков, особенно от всяких "реактивов", только палки в колеса себе суете сейчас ими.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а разве данный подход не будет ломать всю CleanArchitecture когда в VM и в Models у нас будет бизнес логика?

Comment: Я вам советую для начала выучить MVVM, написать на нем проект **правильно**, а уже потом думать о чем-то другом. Ведь сейчас вы грубо его нарушаете, прикрываясь "чистой архитектурой"... У вас должно быть все разделено на **мало связанные** друг с другом слои, а вы суете VM в V, когда как по правилам MVVM, V вообще ничего не должна знать про другие слои, как и другие слои не должны ничего знать про V.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ к сожалению так и не понял где вы это увидели, так как у меня есть строгое разграничение  биндимся на VM и от него уже подписываемся на изменения, всё как в классическом MVVM, если сможете привести пример с MVVM + CleanArchitecture буду очень признателен

Comment: "V вообще ничего не должна знать про другие слои, как и другие слои" - сомневаюсь что это так, так как при Binding мы как минимум уже прописываем команды и свойства которые будут лежать в VM и получаем их

Comment: "де вы это увидели" - ну, может я прицепился к вашей фразе "а ViewModels соответственно в UI". Если у вас весь код из вопроса лежит в отдельном классе и ни как не связан с UI элементами, то значит мои догадки мимо. "привести пример" - не, я пасс) "сомневаюсь что это так" - привязка по типу `"{Binding SomeProperty}"` - это скажем так, абстракция, где есть просто строковое значение, по которому потом ищется свойство, оно не обязательно должно быть, вы можете написать `"{Binding 123}"` и ваш проект успешно запустится, просто не выведет на экран. А вот `textBox.Text = ""` - это уже нарушение.